# screen mirroring to amazon firestick

Tags: screen, amazon

I am running ubuntu 20.10 and own an amazon firestick

is it possible to mirror the screen to the firestick ?

thanks!

Comment: *Technically*, yes. The Amazon Fire Stick accepts Miracast mirroring, which you can set up [following the instructions on this site](https://gadgetstouse.com/blog/2020/08/31/how-to-mirror-your-android-or-iphone-screen-to-firestick/). There are two Miracast options for Ubuntu that I’m aware of, [which I wrote about here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1309528/1091774). So long as you don’t mind testing solutions, it should be possible to broadcast to the TV.

Comment: Thx. I can mirror my android easily (as described in the first link). The second link implies that I cannot mirror the screen while connected to the same wifi as the firestick. I have no wired connection available, so unfortunately that would not be an option...