# How to stream a video file or do mirroring from Ubuntu to your TV?

Tags: software-recommendation, screen, sharing, streaming, video-streaming

On Windows, I can use [airparrot](https://www.airsquirrels.com/airparrot/) to stream everywhere, on apple tv devices, and on smart tv devices.
I can do mirroring and file streaming, I believe Windows 10 supports a built-in screen mirroring and file streaming utility for their users.
How can I do such stuff on Ubuntu? paid or free, doesn't matter, (but of course free is the better :D)

- **side note**: I want to do that Wirelessly, and not via an HDMI cable or something like that. probably over WIFI or Bluetooth

Comment: I couldn't find any application for Ubuntu, now I am looking for something on guthub, there must be someone written a code for such a simple service,

Comment: maybe I'll have to use OBS and stream to a local RTMP server on my network, I just have to find some implementation of an RTMP server on github.
I know that seems garbage comparing to the easy life of the Windows users, but what to do?

Comment: [This might give you a little info](https://askubuntu.com/a/1309528/1222991) to get you started ...

Comment: I have a Synology DS220j NAS mounted (through fstab) as a SAMBA share using cifs and can copy video files to the File Station facility on the NAS and they are automatically seen on my Samsung smart TV which is connected on the same network by Ethernet to the common router/switch on the home network.